# How to get the value from URL parameter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I've an URL like http://example.com/test/sample&fname=hello&lname=world which will display a page called say '*Home.html*'

I need to get those values **hello** and **world** from the URL and use it in the ng-init directive which I have in same '*Home.html*'.

```
<div ng-init="init('val1','val2')"></div>
```

Where **val1** should contain **hello** and **val2** should contain **world**?

Is it possible to do it in AngularJS and is it the right way to approach it? Please help me out!

Comment: you don't need to use the ng-init, use $routeParams or $location in your controller and set scope values from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid using ng-init instead use controller

```
function SomeController($scope, $location){
    var fname = $location.search().fname;    

}
```

Answer (score 3):

With AngularJS you can read querystring parameters using `$location.search`, like so:

```
var init = function() {
    var val1 = $location.search()['val1'];
    var val2 = $location.search()['val2'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does not seems to work with latest AngularJS